# Workflow: Pause for Duration SPD WF Action hangs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Currently, I'm developing a SPOnline workflow trying to automatically assign a task monthly, quarterly, or yearly based on a drop down box value.  From what I've been testing, the pause for duration, set at 5 minutes, seems to hang and does not resume the workflow after pausing.  I have tried removing the pause for duration action and have had a successful task assignment.  Heres how it flows currently with the problem:

Step / Action

1 / Workflow Initialized

2 / Determine Month/Qtr/Year based on drop down list

3 / Pause based DDL value (This is where it hangs)

4 / Set document approval status to Pending

5 / Assign a task

6 / Set document approval status to Completed

No matter what time interval I set it to, it seems to hang and not complete the workflow or go to the next task.  I've tried the following steps:

•   Debugging the workflow by removing pause for duration step

•   Changed regional settings to match server

•   Broken up workflow actions into multiple steps and vice versa (seeing if pause needs to be seperated out)

•   tried 5,10,15,30 min and 1 hour pauses

Any suggestions on what to look at or if Pause for Duration is not working properly?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There was a hotfix to address a problem with the "pause for duration" actions not firing.  However, I think this was rolled into SP1, so you should have that applied already:

[Hot fix blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdesigner/archive/2007/05/02/hotfix-for-delay-need-better-title.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I saw that, but I think that applies to the server product.  This is "SharePoint in the cloud" which some elements of server dont apply such as IRM.  It's almost as if there is a lack of timer on this.  

I just checked my WF statuses and the daily one is hung now too.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=256CE3C3-6A42-4953-8E1B-E0BF27FD465B&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I'm getting the same behavior with SP2 installed. Several "Pause for Duration" WFAs which should have paused for 3 minutes each have now been waiting for more than 4 days with no error in the workflow, and all timer jobs reporting healthy in central admin.

There's a post about this on MSDN which suggests that the hotfix only fixed part of the problem: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/1965d387-8436-4868-98dc-7a76cbda75d3/ (that discussion has been locked, thanks MSDN)